# Extracing v, r, s from signature and adding it to a transaction

Tags: ethereumjs, signature, ethereumjs-tx, ecdsa

I am trying to decode the v, r, s from a signature and add that to a transaction and broadcast at some point.
When I convert the signature into v,r,s and build the raw tx the from: parameter does not match with the signed address.

What am i doing wrong?

```
const txData = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(100000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(50 * 1e9), // 5 gwei
    to: destinationAddres,
    value: web3.utils.toHex("0.01", "ether")

}

const transaction = new ethereumjs.Tx(txData, { chain: "mainnet" });

const serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString("hex");
console.log('SERIALIZED TX: ' + serializedTx);

const signature = await web3.eth.sign(web3.utils.sha3(serializedTx), '0xCd91D6bCA426C655f2b484D1347ebc2cA4e8ac80')

console.log('SIGNATURE: ' + signature);

r = signature.slice(0, 66)
s = '0x' + signature.slice(66, 130)
v = '0x' + signature.slice(130, 132)
v = web3.utils.toDecimal(v)

// var v = '28';
console.log('R: ' + r);
console.log('S: ' + s);
console.log('V: ' + v);

const signedTxData = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(100000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(50 * 1e9), // 5 gwei
    to: destinationAddres,
    value: web3.utils.toHex("0.01", "ether"),
    chainId: 1,
    r: r,
    s: s,
    v: v
}


console.log('tx signed: ', signedTxData);
const serializedTxRSV = new ethereumjs.Tx(signedTxData).serialize().toString('hex');
console.log('FINAL RAW TX: ' + serializedTxRSV)
```

When I decode the final raw TX:

```
  "nonce": 0,
  "gasPrice": 50000000000,
  "gasLimit": 100000,
  "to": "0xcd91d6bca426c655f2b484d1347ebc2ca4e8ac80",
  "value": 33048495391913270,
  "data": "",
  "from": "0x9e8f46060d8eb68d028854c7eee98bce9ff28e9c",
  "r": "a9627386922cb359c523cb34789f7954dff278a54e2e5ab550f75ca17b75226b",
  "v": "1b",
  "s": "36e937e919973b338cfe2dc962bd8c12a7ee627a5bc9f16260b078ab97f7c1ff"
}
```

As you can see the from: does not match with the signer address

Comment: hi misterBulle i wonder if you were able to solve this

Comment: if it's like Bitcoin, there is one byte that tells the length of r and s. It should be like this: v is the first byte, length r is second byte, then r, then length s (also 1 byte), then s.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you are signing with `sha3` but ethereum uses keccak256. use this

```
 web3.utils.soliditySha3(serializedTx)
```

or follow the [@ethereumjs/tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethereumjs/tx) example

```
import { Chain, Common, Hardfork } from '@ethereumjs/common'
import { Transaction } from '@ethereumjs/tx'

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  value: '0x00',
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057',
}

const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Mainnet, hardfork: Hardfork.Istanbul })
const tx = Transaction.fromTxData(txParams, { common })

const privateKey = Buffer.from(
  'e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109',
  'hex'
)

const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey)

const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize()
```